# Control lost his value on post

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, webforms

I got a `select` with the jquery uniform apply on. This select is in a form. When the form is post, the `SelectedValue` of my control is totally empty.

I tried to call `$.uniform.update();` on the change event, but it haven't work.

The weirdest thing in this case is that when I call `$("mySelect").val()` the return value is the good one.

Can someone help me on this one?

**Edit1:** The value ( `$("#mySelect").val()` ) of the control is good even without doing the uniform update command. The problem is realy in passing the value to my C# code.

**Edit2:** I just found that the selected value is in fact always the first element of the `select`.

**Edit3:** I try to remove the aristo from the control and the selected value is still the first children in the `select`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is ASP.net WebForms appilication, you have to check:

1. Your control is marked as server ( runat="server" )
2. You have correspodning protected field on Page ( protected TextBox myTextBox; )
3. ViewState is enabled

Comment: And be sure that the control is not bind on the postback. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your ID in the parenthesis.  I know it's not necessary, per their documentation, but I've always had success that way.

```
$.uniform.update("#mySelect");
```

Comment: I just change the title of the question, because I found that the cause was not uniform.